# Why ViewState is not available in class library project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

I have a situation while uploading file . If file upload control has file then it will pick the path from file upload control else it will the path saved in `ViewState["ImagePath"]`.

I want to make it generic so that , wherever I need such upload scenario I can use it. But while implementing I cant see, If I can use `ViewState` in a class library project.

I have following two questions in mind:

1. Is there anyway to access the `ViewState` for current page in class library project?
2. If above is not possible, then Why? AFAIK almost everything is available for 
   class library project. Then why not `ViewState`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) View State

> Gets a dictionary of state information that allows you to save and restore the view state of a server control across multiple requests for the same page.

The pages `ViewState` is not accessible to other `classes`.  Each `Page` and `UserControl` maintains their own `private viewstate`. if you need to access if from outside of the page, then you could expose the `ViewState` value as a `public property` of the page.

Comment: You can use session variable to store this value and get session varialbe value using `HttpContext` in class library project